# Marklogic Datahub: Problem with the JSON file content while creating a "Mapping" step in Data Hub

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I am using Data Hub Quick Start V5.4.0 and Marklogic Version 10.0-6.0

I have a JSON file with the following content in data-hub-STAGING,

```
{
"A1_Key": "A1_Value", 
"A2_Key": "A2_Value", 
"A3_Key": "A3_Value", 
"A4_Key": "A4_Value", 
"A5_Key": "A5_Value", 
"A6_Key": "A6_Value"
}
```

For this file, while creating a "mapping" step in the Data Hub, this file is expanded properly in the "Source Data" section (Refer to the below image)

[image: Source Data Expanded Successfully]

But when the above JSON file is updated as like below:

```
[
  {
    "A1_Key": "A1_Value", 
    "A2_Key": "A2_Value", 
    "A3_Key": "A3_Value", 
    "A4_Key": "A4_Value", 
    "A5_Key": "A5_Value", 
    "A6_Key": "A6_Value"
  },
  {
    "B1_Key": "B1_Value", 
    "B2_Key": "B2_Value", 
    "B3_Key": "B3_Value", 
    "B4_Key": "B4_Value", 
    "B5_Key": "B5_Value", 
    "B6_Key": "B6_Value"
  }
]
```

When creating a "mapping" step in the Data Hub, this file is not expanded in the "Source Data" section (Refer to the below image)

[image: Source Data not expanded correctly]

Below are the settings for the mapping step:

[image: Mapping_Step_Settings]

Is there any problem with the content of the JSON file? or how to go ahead with the "mapping" step?